# How to convert type "int" to type "LPCSTR" in Win32 C++

Tags: c++, winapi, messagebox

Hello friends how can I convert type "int" to type "LPCSTR"? I want to give the variable "int cxClient" to the "MessageBox" function's second parameter "LPCSTR lpText". Following is the sample code:

```
int cxClient;    
cxClient = LOWORD (lParam);    
MessageBox(hwnd, cxClient, "Testing", MB_OK);
```

But it does not work. The following function is the method signature of the "MessageBox" function:

```
MessageBox(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert the int to a string by using the right sprintf variant

```
TCHAR buf[100];
_stprintf(buf, _T("%d"), cxClient);
MessageBox(hwnd, buf, "Testing", MB_OK);
```

you need `<tchar.h>`.

I think `_stprintf` is the quick answer here - but if you want to go pure C++ like David suggests, then

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
wostringstream oss;
#else
ostringstream oss;
#endif

oss<<cxClient;

MessageBox(0, oss.str().c_str(), "Testing", MB_OK);
```

You need

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Since the question is tagged C++, perhaps a C++ answer would be better

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - adding one with ostringstream also.

Comment: Wow! I got it. Now the "MessageBox" function can display the variable I want :D . Following is my working code:

    #include <sstream>
    using namespace std;
    #ifdef _UNICODE
    wostringstream oss;
    #else
    ostringstream oss;
    #endif
    
    oss<<cxClient;
    MessageBox(hwnd, oss.str().c_str(), "Testing", MB_OK);

Thank you so much
:D

Comment: @Bhaddiya Instead of the conditional code you could also use `typedef std::basic_ostringstream<TCHAR> tostringstream`. Alternatively use `wostringstream` together with the UNICODE-variant `MessageBoxW`.

Answer (score 2):

```
using std::to_string

std::string message = std::to_string(cxClient)
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: Note that `std::to_string` requires C++11